# Splitting a pdf File into Chunks and reassemble it again in Java

Tags: java, file, pdf, split, chunks

I am trying to split the pdf files into chunks and after processing(Anything like transferring from one server to another or saving into Filesystem) need to reassemble them into original one.

Then original file should be equal to reassemble file.

Note : Pdf file contains images, diagram etc

Is there anyway to do that ?

Note : Actually i want to transfer the pdf to any server/directory where i should transfer a pdf with limited size so for big size pdfs i need to split into small pdfs and send them one by one and then again reassemble them in target directory/place and it should be as original pdf. but some how i am not able to achieve once merged them in target. It changes its size but content i can see same for both original and merged pdf.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by chunks?

Comment: @mkl split into multiple part.

Comment: Simply split like the first part containing the first MB, the second part the second MB, etc? Splitting and reassembling like that is trivial and does not depend on the file being a PDF, let alone its contents. Or do you expect the parts to be functional PDFs by themselves?

Comment: Actually i want to transfer the pdf to any server/directory where i should transfer a pdf with limited size so for big size pdfs i need to split into small pdfs and send them one by one and then again reassemble them in target directory/place and it should be as original pdf. but some how i am not able to achieve once merged them in target. It changes its size but content i can see same for both original and merged pdf. @mkl

Comment: *"It changes its size but content i can see same for both original and merged pdf."* - Can you share an example file before and after splitting and recombining by your code? We can analyze them and probably fix your code.